# Smart way to use .csv files to store multiple data series in Python?

Tags: python, csv

Say I have got some data series generated by my plotting application, and I want to store them and recall them in .csv at will.

Each data set has four characteristics. A name, a set of x values (`xvals`), a set of y values (`yvals`) and a parent.

I'm currently imagining a .csv file the kind that I would generate in Excel, and I'm thinking:

```
name, DataSet1
xvals, 1,2,3,4,5
yvals, 1,4,9,16,25
parent, None
<linebreak>
name, DataSet2
xvals, 1,2,3,4,5
yvals, 21,23,24,25,26
parent, None
<linebreak>
```

and so on. It doesn't feel very natural, and the implementation is looking kind of ugly. Does anyone have any suggestions?

In my application, each DataSeries instance already contains all the data I need. If I could actuallly save the instance object itself (or a collection of them) that would work just as well for the meantime (although I eventually want to be able to export the data for usage in Excel)

I want to tell python:

1. read all the lines in the file. every time you read a "blank" line, insert a separator. consider each clump of lines a data set.
2. read the first item in each line of the package. this is the type of information the rest of the cells in the row contain. take that referral, and put the data in all the adjacent cells, as a list, into the corresponding object attribute.

I have a way to make this happen, but it involves a lot of awkward specific calls to characters and positions which reminds me of the "GOTO" statement. I want something more organic and Pythonic.

Current approach:

```
class DataSet(object):
    def __init__(self, name, xvals, yvals, parent=None):
        self.name = name
        self.xvals = xvals
        self.yvals = yvals
        self.parent = parent

loaded_data = csv.reader(open('csv_data.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')

container = []
dict = {}
for row in loaded_data:
    if list(row)[0] == '':
        container.append(dict)
        dict = {}
    else:
        dict[list(row)[0]] = filter(None,list(row)[1:])
container.append(dict)
```

Comment: Check out the `dump()` and `dumps()` functions in both the `pickle` and `json` modules to store your DataSeries instance(s) onto disk.

Comment: I'd work backwards and first determine what the best format for your data would be in Excel for ease of manipulation there and have that determine the best CSV layout to use.

Comment: the format I show up above would be perfectly suitable. I have added sample code that somewhat fulfills my needs, but in dire need of improvement.

Comment: You don't need to say `list()` around each `row` read. `row` is a `list`. Also don't use tabs in the code you display here on stackoverflow use spaces otherwise it doesn't come out right when displayed.

Comment: Could you put all of one entire dataset on one row?

Comment: How is the data being used in Excel?  Are multiple datasets in a single worksheet?  Is each dataset placed in it's own worksheet?  I think the answers that mention going backwards from how the engineers want to see it in Excel, and then implementing the code make the most sense . . .

Comment: Does the number of x and y values vary between datasets and if so, is there a maximum possible number?

Comment: Hey,

The data just needs to be very user-friendly in Excel.

And yes, the number of x and y values will vary wildly depending on the modeling parameters chosen. However, I'm making headway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make data set and parent into columns, so your data looks like this:

```
"Dataset","Parent","XVal","YVal"
DataSet1,None,1,1
DataSet1,None,2,4
...
DataSet2,None,1,21
DataSet2,None,2,23
```

In general to make your data into a tabular format (like CSV), you need to restructure it as rows.  If you have information that is associated not with a row but with some group of rows (e.g., the "data set name"), you should recast this is a column whose value is duplicated through the relevant rows.  When you read in the data, you can easily filter on this column to get the relevant groups back.

Incidentally, you might want to look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), a library that provides useful tools for dealing with tabular data (including reading and writing CSVs and grouping on column values in the way I described).

Edit: Based on your comments, it appears you're not asking how to use CSV to store your data.  You're asking how to parse your ad hoc format.  The answer to that is "write a parser yourself"; you could have a look at [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/).  CSV libraries won't parse it for you, because your format isn't really CSV.  Spreadsheets won't work well with your format because it's not tabular.  If you want to use premade tools to handle your data, you need to change your data to use a preexisting format.  This will lead to easier processing in the long run, and changing your data into the right format isn't that difficult.

Comment: This is interesting and would do in a pinch for personal purposes, but I am eventually passing this code onto the next summer student who decides to participate in this research. I really feel that I should try to stick to my original conception of data sets up there above.

I have updated my question with additional info.

Comment: @RodericDay You really only have two options. 1) Structure your data so that it is square/tabular as BrenBarn suggests here. This is good for analysis with statistical software and for displaying in excel. Or 2) Maintain the structure of the data you have internally and dump in into a hierarchical structure like json. If you go with csv, look at the csv module: http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: @RodericDay: What you are describing is not really a CSV file.  If you want to use CSV, you need to make your data tabular.  If you don't want to make your data tabular, forget CSV and use something like JSON as suggested by Wilduck.  I would add that if you are passing the data on to someone else, it is far better to use a common format (like CSV or JSON) than to try to hack together some ad-hoc format that the next person will have difficulty dealing with.

Comment: I'm not trying to hack together a new format. I want to use CSV, I just don't think populating rows vertically and attaching an owner to every single value will lend itself very well to manipulating the data later in Excel.

Edit: I see what you mean about square/tabular... but there has to be a way to make this work.

Comment: If you think your format will work in Excel, try loading it and see how it works.  My bet is it won't work very well.  Just because it has commas in it doesn't make it CSV.  CSV data should be tabular, and this is doubly true if you intend to import it into a spreadsheet.  You may be able to write Python code to parse your format, but you won't be able to get Excel to parse it.

Comment: btw, be aware that `csv` will not turn the "None" in the file into a Python `None` value.

Comment: A more concise layout would be `"Dataset","Parent","XVal1","XVal2,..."YVal1","YVal2"...` and would eliminate the need for blank lines between datasets.

Comment: @martineau That format would only work if there are the same number of x-values and y-values in every dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using csv, you could use json. The `json` module is good for [serializing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) non tabular data. So, if you have a list of data sets, something like this:

```
data_sets = [{"name": "DataSet1", "xvals": [1,2,3,4,5], 
              "yvals": [1,4,9,16,25], "parent": None},
             {"name": "DataSet2", "xvals": [1,2,3,4,5], 
              "yvals": [21,23,24,25,26], "parent": None}]
```

you should have no trouble exporting and importing that data into a file using json.

```
import json

# export to a file
with open("path/to/file.json", "wb") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(data_sets))

# import from a file
with open("path/to/file.json", "rb") as f:
    loaded_data = json.loads(f.read())

print loaded_data
```

This won't help you load the data into excel, but it provides a convenient way of dumping simple python data structures into a file for later.

Note though, that when loading from a json file, you'll end up with unicode objects instead of python's basic `str` object, which can look a little weird in python 2. For example, after you've executed the lines above, notice the `u` before each key:

```
>>> print loaded_data[0]
{u'xvals': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], u'yvals': [1, 4, 9, 16, 25], 
u'name': u'DataSet1', u'parent': None}
```

That just means the keys are unicode strings now. This isn't a bad thing, and will still compare just fine to normal `str` objects:

```
>>> 'xvals' == u'xvals'
True
>>> print loaded_data[0]['xvals']
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This looks neat and I will explore it for personal use, but I really want to output to .csv as it will allow the rest of the engineers to readily use the output.